# Facebook browser statistics

Tags: facebook, browser

I'm looking for an authoritative source on which browsers people browse facebook with.  Specifically, I'm curious what percent IE6 and IE7 are at.

I constantly run into issues with IE7 on Facebook, and am trying to determine if it's worth my time to search for solutions.

Comment: This is a programming question, it just doesn't have a programming answer.  If there's a better place to ask this, please vote to move it, but don't vote to close!  If the answer is available, it's extremely valuable to a number of developers.

Comment: The only close request is mine and I didn't vote to close, I voted to move to webmasters stackexchange. It is the better place I suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt if Facebook would release that private information.

You could use your own web server's log files (the server that hosts your facebook app) and get stats from those files. But I presume, you don't have access to those.  So you might be able to make a guess by checking out the global stats here:  http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php or http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp

**EDIT**
Some information from a hosting company about its Facebook stats. However, this information is from 2009. :|

https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=94523840758

Comment: I've reviewed any info I can find and made a guess; I'd like to confirm it if I could.  Whenever I browse fbook in IE7, I get random errors; I'm really curious how many people put up with these errors.

Comment: What do your server logs for your facebook apps show?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has announced they are [dropping support for IE7](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/facebook/facebook-phasing-out-support-for-internet-explorer-7/6729) (they already no longer support IE6).  They have not announced numbers as far as I know.  I doubt it will be worth it for you to support it as well for your Facebook app.

Comment: To quote the article "This is the beginning of the end for IE7 support on Facebook, even if the company hasn’t yet said anything officially."  I agree 100% with your view, but it'd be nice to have numbers to back it.